# How do I paste a section of text into an existing frame in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I've been working on a file in Word and I simply want to insert some text into an existing frame by copying and pasting from another document but when I do so, for some reason it pastes it outside the frame, directly below it, which is not what I want.  I've looked at the auto formatting options under proofing in Word Options but haven't been able to find anything to fix the problem so wondering if anyone knows a solution. Below is a screenshot showing what I want to achieve.

[image]

Comment: To be clear: Is it a frame or a text box? These are different things in Word and behave differently; but I've sometimes heard people use the terms interchangeably. If it's truly a frame, is the paragraph style that's applied to the paragraphs for item 'G' the same as the style applied to the item 'F' and 'H' paragraphs? Or, is the style/are the styles applied to item 'G' paragraphs formatted to be enclosed in a frame? A frame setting needs to be explicitly applied to the paragraph style.

Comment: @cnread Thanks for your response. I actually don't know if this is a frame or text box. I'm just using a template that's been sent to me. I guess it's a frame but I have only just come across the term, so I don't know off the top of my head the answer to this or your other questions as I have no knowledge of styles or frames at the moment. I haven't encountered such awkwardness before with text boxes though: it won't let me expand the box downwards at all either. The box actually begins on the page above.

Comment: @cnread We actually got round the problem by using a different template which was for the same type of document as this seemed to be the quickest and easiest solution. The frames or text boxes on this other template weren't entirely free from awkwardness but were significantly less awkward for a styles novice like me to work with.